# React auto wrapping higher-order components inside of ul elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a higher-order component that I need to use both inside `<ul>` and non-list elements.  The `<li>`s are styled to add padding / dividers between them, etc.  I don't want to wrap the higher-order component in an `<li>`, as it's clickable and the click target would then be reduced due to the padding on the `<li>`.

I figured I'd just pass in a prop to the component so that I could change it's base element type depending on where it was being used:

```
const Component = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      elementType: 'li',
    };
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <this.props.elementType onClick={ ... }>
        { content }
      </this.props.elementType>
    );
  },
});
```

And it seems to be rendering the base element correctly.  However, when I use this inside a `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
  <Component />
  <Component />
</ul>
```

React automatically wraps `Component` in a `<li>` (even though it's base element is already an `<li>`) which causes React to complain about nesting `<li>`s within each other: `validateDOMNesting(...): <li> cannot appear as a descendant of <li>.`

I'm using React 15.0.2.  I know they recently took out adding in `<span>`s and instead use react-text comment nodes such as `<!-- react-text: 75 -->"text"<!-- /react-text -->`, so I'm a little confused as to why this functionality didn't change as well.

I'm curious if there's a way to get around this automatic wrapping, or if I just have to work around this by applying styles to elements within the `<li>`s instead of to the `<li>`s themselves.

**Edit**: This happens with the non-jsx syntax as well:

```
React.createElement(
  this.props.elementType,
  ...
)
```

**EDIT**: This appears to have been some kind of really weird caching issue. I was able to get the expected behaviour again by commenting and then uncommenting the second Component. :S

Comment: what's `content` ?

Comment: `content` is just an `<i>` and a `<span>`, no `<li>` elements at all.

When I look at the rendered output too, it's `<ul><li><li>content</li></li></ul>`, and the warning errors persist even when changing content to a string.

Comment: I think something else is going on.. this doesn't happen to me http://www.webpackbin.com/NJJyOfiK-

Comment: @azium your example doesn't use it as a hoc, not sure if that matters to be honest

Comment: Um.. I just copied exactly what's in your question. You don't appear to be using an HOC either. Did you forget a function call?

Comment: @azium It's not my question i'm just an observer :) I just assumed by the title/context that content would be another component

Comment: @aw04 ah! sorry didn't notice, yes there is no HOC going on here, but to be fair lots of people are confused by the confusing fact that HOCs are functions that returns components, not components themselves.

Comment: Sure, yes I can't speak to the ops definition of a hoc, just pointing out a potential difference.

Comment: @aw04 If content were a component it would need to be `<Content />` unless this particular usage was `hoc(<Content />)` which I think is rare

Comment: @azium Something is missing either way, but yes

Comment: Hmm, yeah @azium, I haven't been able to create a case on webpackbin that has the same errors as I'm seeing, even when updating to my version of react and react-dom... I'll continue investigating.

Comment: Ok, so this is super weird.  I couldn't create a reproducible case on webpackbin, so I started changing things around on my site again to see if I could pinpoint what was causing the problem.  When I comment out the second Component (there are actually two rendered side-by-side in the ul) it worked fine and did not add an additional li.  When I then uncommented that line, it also works fine.  I had two views (desktop and mobile versions) that were having this problem, and both behaved in this same manner.  I have the cache disabled and am completely baffled as to what might be going on.

Comment: I don't really see how this could have been a caching issue, as I was seeing the changes I was making, but somehow it kept that surrounding <li> even though it was removed from the code.  I'm also unsure why commenting out the line and then uncommenting it fixed it... Very confusing.